# How to parse json items using python?

Tags: python, json, parsing

I am trying to parse the following json data but i keep getting error:

```
Error Type: <type 'exceptions.KeyError'>
Error Contents: ('channel',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
data=channels['channel']
KeyError: ('channel',)
-->End of Python script error report<--
```

could any one show me how to fix above error and parse the required data from json.Thanks in advance.

python:

```
url2 ='http://www.awebsite.com/json.php';
response = make_request(url2)
channels=json.loads(response)
data=channels['channel']

for item in data:
    name=item['title']
    thumb=item['logo']

    url=item['url1']
    add_link(name,url,4,thumb, thumb)
```

json :

```
  {
        "channels": [{
            "channel": {
                "id": "1",
                "title": "test1",
                "logo": "https:\/\/somewebsite.com\/1.jpg",
                "url1": "http:\/\/somewebsite2.com:80\/live\/hls\/1.m3u8",

            }
        }, {
            "channel": {
                "id": "2",
                "title": "test2",
                "logo": "https:\/\/somewebsite.com\/2.jpg",
                "url1": "http:\/\/somewebsite2.com:80\/live\/hls\/2.m3u8",
               }
        }]
    }
```

Comment: the first step in your debugging should be to look at the content of your object to see what kind of keys you have there, since `channel` is not one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot letter `s` in word `channels`.It has to be `data=channels['channels']` <- see last s

You have data

```
channels['channels'][0]['channel']['id']
channels['channels'][0]['channel']['title']

channels['channels'][1]['channel']['id']
channels['channels'][1]['channel']['title']
```

not

```
channels['channel'][0]['id']
channels['channel'][0]['title']

channels['channel'][1]['id']
channels['channel'][1]['title']
```

Use `print(channels)` to see it.

---

**EDIT:** working example

```
response = '''  {
        "channels": [{
            "channel": {
                "id": "1",
                "title": "test1",
                "replay": false,
                "description": "",
                "epg_id": null,
                "genre": "35",
                "pin": false,
                "server": "1",
                "genre": "Other",
                "logo": "https:\/\/somewebsite.com\/1.jpg",
                "url1": "http:\/\/somewebsite2.com:80\/live\/hls\/1.m3u8",
                "url2": "http:\/\/somewebsite2:80\/live\/hls\/1.m3u8",
                "dvr_url": ""
            }
        }, {
            "channel": {
                "id": "2",
                "title": "test2",
                "replay": false,
                "description": "",
                "epg_id": null,
                "genre": "27",
                "pin": false,
                "server": "2",
                "genre": "Movies",
                "logo": "https:\/\/somewebsite.com\/2.jpg",
                "url1": "http:\/\/somewebsite2.com:80\/live\/hls\/2.m3u8",
                "url2": "http:\/\/somewebsite2.com:80\/live\/hls\/2.m3u8",
                "dvr_url": ""

               }
        }]
    }'''

import json

data = json.loads(response)
channels = data['channels']

for item in channels:
    name = item['channel']['title']
    thumb = item['channel']['logo']
    cat = item['channel']['genre']
    url = item['channel']['url1']
    #add_link(name, url, 4, thumb, thumb)
    print(name, url, thumb, cat)
```

Comment: Thanks for replies. Furas i getint first set of data only inside "for item in data " should i use counter to increment the index (like php)?

Comment: You don't have to use index. Python code mostly doesn't use index.

Answer (score 0):

`channels=json.loads(response)` creates a Python dictionary called `channels`. The top level of this dictionary (based on the json you included) is `channels['channels']`. You get a key error when you try `channels['channel']` because that key does not exist at the first level of your dictionary.

In order to access a `channel` entity, try: `channels['channels'][1]['channel']`

You need the "`[1]`" because `channels['channels']` is a list of `channel` entities.

You can easily build your data with this knowlege:

```
data = [channel['channel'] for channel in channels['channels']]
```